# Test crashing when creating a linked list with 104634 nodes

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures

I'm noticing an interesting behaviour. I've been testing the performance of constructing a linked list with many elements. For some reason, past a certain amount of deallocations, the test with crash.

Here's my LinkedList implementation:

```
class LinkedList<T> {
  let data: T
  var next: LinkedList?

  init(data: T, next: LinkedList? = nil) {
    self.data = data
    self.next = next
  }

  func cons(_ data: T) -> LinkedList {
    return LinkedList(data: data, next: self)
  }
}
```

I am testing this using the `XCTest` library. I made this test function:

```
let number = 104633
func testPerformanceExample() {
  self.measure {
    var list = LinkedList<Int>(data: 5)
    for i in 0..<number {
      list = list.cons(i)
    }
  }
}
```

I spent a fair amount of time trying to home into this number. It seems that if I try to construct a LinkedList with **104634** nodes, I get a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5a059ff8)` crash, and the debug navigator shows a tower of `LinkedList.deinit` calls:

[image: debug screenshot]

Another interesting thing is that if you move the list outside of the test function, it no longer crashes:

```
var list = LinkedList<Int>(data: 5)

func testPerformanceExample() {
  self.measure {
    for i in 0..<self.number {
      self.list = self.list.cons(i)
    }
  }
}
```

I curious as to why a long series of deallocations can cause a crash. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

This crash also occurs when you run the code outside of a `XCTestCase`. I've got this code in a `UIViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let number = 1046340
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let date = Date()
    var list = LinkedList<Int>(data: 0, next: nil)
    for i in 0..<number {
      list = list.cons(i)
    }
    let timeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince(date)

    print(timeInterval)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not compile your test.
[image]

This code worked with 100x as many nodes. I don't think the self reference is your problem but it does indicate that you are using an older Swift version. Upgrade your tools and try again.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. I added `print` statement like you and added the breakpoint. The breakpoint triggered normally. It seems like the crash comes after the test completes. 

Tweak your number to `1046340` so it's quicker to run the test, then remove the breakpoint. 

As for tools, I believe I'm using the latest. I'm using Xcode version 8.2.1 (8C1002). Not sure what you mean by `self` reference.

Comment: I think you're on to the something with the deinit. I'm wondering if XCTestCase does something fancy at the end of methods to determine success / failure and the huge amount of deallocations is messing something up. If you make the data property of the list weak (which breaks the functionality but...) you'll see the problem doesn't happen, and the deallocations happen during the loop instead of all at the same time at the end of the function scope.

Comment: @AndrewCarter It's not just `XCTestCase`, I tried doing this in the `viewDidLoad` method of a view controller. I ran the app and it crashed the app.

Comment: woah good to know. I'm still playing with it to see if I can find a way to prevent it while still defining the initial list in the same scope.

Comment: Just curious, is yours working fine for 104633 nodes? On my computer, it crashes right at 104634, but 104633 works fine.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is that it'll crash right before the last one because after that is when all the deallocations happen, which is when the crash happens. Can you post your code that shows the issue happening inside a UIViewController? I don't get the crash outside of a test case.

Comment: @AndrewCarter I've appended the ViewController code to the original post. It seems that the amount of nodes I needed to create for the crash has changed. I had to increase the number of nodes by a magnitude to see the crash.

Comment: I think you've hit this same problem (bug?)
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13744
EDIT: Another good link with more discussion and work arounds https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24011

Comment: Adding the manual release of the list with `while (list.next != nil) { list = list.next! }` to the end of the test function does work.

Comment: @PriceRingo, seems like manual release must be done to avoid the automatic deallocation proccess.